Why is Elixir `mix` asking me to install the same version of `hex` with an `.ez` at the end?
Main Question
I'm brand new to Elixir, so I don't know how to answer this question from mix local.hex:
$ mix local.hex
Found existing entry: /home/civfan/.asdf/installs/elixir/1.17.2-otp-27/.mix/archives/hex-2.1.1
Are you sure you want to replace it with "https://builds.hex.pm/installs/1.16.0/hex-2.1.1.ez"? [Yn]

This is in an empty directory -- including no .tool-versions or any other dot files.
$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 civfan civfan 4096 Aug  2 11:49 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 civfan civfan 4096 Jul 26 13:58 ..

My terminal environment is configured to use Elixir v1.17.2.
$ asdf list
elixir
 *1.17.2-otp-27
erlang
 *27.0.1

$ asdf current
elixir          1.17.2-otp-27   /home/civfan/.tool-versions
erlang          27.0.1          /home/civfan/.tool-versions


$ elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 27 [erts-15.0.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

Elixir 1.17.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 27)

Note that before using asdf, I did install Erlang using apt before finding I needed a newer version. I uninstalled it using apt before using asdf, but as is standard, whatever config there is for the package is still there, according to dpkg (ie. it says rc):
$ dpkg -l | egrep "(erla|lixi)"
rc  erlang-base                                   1:24.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1                          amd64        Erlang/OTP virtual machine and base applications

However, I have now done an apt purge erlang-base to help rule this out, and now there's no trace of it in dpkg. I get the same results with mix local.hex.
I'm confused --

Why is it asking to install hex-2.1.1.ez over hex-2.1.1, when they're both the same version other than a .ez tag at the end?
Why does it seem to think I have or want Elixir v1.16.0's version of hex, when my environment is set to use Elixir v1.17.2?
Does the .ez in the version have any special meaning with Elixir/Erlang?

Grasping
I figure this has something to do with my environment and not replicating the original tutorial's environment.
Yesterday, I followed the standard Elixir installation guides, and using the asdf method got Elixir and Erlang successfully installed. Then I followed the Phoenix framework guide to build and run my first project successfully.
Today, I came back and opened a new terminal, and I'm following another project guide for Elixir. Near the start, it says to run mix local.hex. Aha! I remember Mix, close equivalent to pip in Python, and something about Hex, too, though I'm unclear on the closest equivalent to that. So I'm feeling confident it should just work, but then I got the question above. Maybe it does just work still, but I thought I'd reach out anyway so I make sure I'm on a good foundation.
I did put this in my .bashrc:
 . "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"
 . "$HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"

I can run erl and elixir and mix just fine.
Before this I did setup IntelliJ and the Elixir plugin there, and pointed it at the existing Elixir and Erlang SDKs I installed already through asdf, so I don't think it made any changes. And the current question isn't related to IntelliJ, just command-line.

You explicitly instructed mix to install the version of hex locally, but you already have one, hence the prompt. The tutorial author didn’t know you have it at fingers already, and described the installation from scratch. That said, both are safe, either keep your version, or reinstall it, it does not matter.

It's a new, empty directory. So why would it think it has something locally?

I missed that versions are different (see the answer below,) but in general it does not depend whether it’s a new directory or not, because archives (and mix local.hex does indeed install an archive) are system-wide, not project-wise.

@AlekseiMatiushkin you first said I instructed mix to install the version of hex locally. In the next comment you said it installs it system-wide. These seem to be conflicting. Can you further elaborate what you mean?

“Locally” means on the local machine. Archives are being installed system-wide. Sorry for the confusion.

If you read the 2 file paths, you can see they are using different elixir versions.
1.17.2-otp-27

and
1.16.0

I can not say exactly what is happening in your environment but here is some advice for asdf that is always relevant.
asdf is a lot like pyenv where you have both "global" and "local" versions.
The global versions are set "globally" and are the default/fallback versions.
You can set these like this:
asdf global elixir 1.17.2-otp-27
asdf global erlang 27.0

Now when you run, e.g. iex, it will use these versions.
To set local versions, first realize that these are saved in your current directory.
So do something like this:
cd ~/my-github-projects/cool-new-project
# now you are in your project directory
asdf local elixir 1.16.0
asdf local erlang 26.0

or whatever versions you want for that project.
These asdf local commands will create or append to a file called:
.tool-versions

This "tool versions" file is what asdf will automatically read. If you are in a sub-directory, then asdf will check the parent directory for this file. If it does not find it in the parent directory, then it will check the parent's parent. It will keep moving up through directories until it is in your home directory and then it will revert to the global versions.
So the main question is to see if there is a .tool-versions file in your project directory, like this:
ls -lah

You can even edit this .tool-versions file manually, if you want.
Note that it may hold versions for many other things.
If you ever download/clone a new project that contains a .tool-versions file, then you can install all of the things by simply running:
asdf install

You can use asdf to install lots of other tools, e.g. postgres, nodejs, etc.
You can view all possible versions for a "plugin" (as they call it) like this:
asdf list all elixir

Although this will only work if asdf already knows about the elixir "plugin", which you only have to do 1 time, like this:
asdf plugin add nodejs

You can see all the possible plugins with this fun command:
asdf plugin list all

If you forget all of this, you can get help remembering it by simply running:
asdf

which will display a summary of all the commands.
I hope this helps!

This is very helpful, thank you. I'm still unclear why it wants to install the elixir 1.16.0 version of hex-2.1.1.ez, when asdf shows it is using 1.17.2-otp-27.

what does elixir --version return?

Same, Elixir 1.17.2 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 27). See edited question for full output.

It is bizarre. I have no idea what the true cause is.
